# How to Check a Variable Within a Class?

Tags: c++, class, object

I'm just starting to learn about C++ classes, and I had a question regarding how to check a variable for each object without cycling through them using if-statements.
Here is my code:

```
    
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    string ans;


    class Weapon {
    
    public:
        string name;
        int damage;
        bool isCurrentWeapon;
        
        
    public:
    
    Weapon(string n, int d, bool iCW){
        name = n;
        damage = d;
        isCurrentWeapon = iCW;
    }
    };


    int main()
    {
    Weapon sword("Sword",30,true);
    Weapon dagger("Dagger",10,false);
    cout<<"Welcome to the Weapon Shop! Your current weapon is: " XXXXXXX
    return 0;
    }
```

My question is how would I replace the XXXXXXX with the current weapon? I'd like to somehow check out of ALL of the objects in the class, which one has `isCurrentWeapon` set to `true`. And I'd like to do this without using if-statements to individually check each weapon.

I tried to use a static variable, but I decided that that probably wasn't right, as each instance of `Weapon` has the variable `isCurrentWeapon`.

Thanks!

(If there is a better title for this question please edit it - I just couldn't think of a way to describe it better.)

Comment: You have this backwards.  Get rid of `isCurrentWeapon` and replace it with a variable holding a pointer to the current `Weapon`.

Comment: You'll probably need to keep a collection of all these weapons, and loop through them to find the current one.

Comment: You probably want a second `Hero` or `Player` class and in that class you have a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Weapon>>` containing the weapons. You could avoid the looping through the list if you had a separate pointer to the "active" weapon which is either a nullpointer or points to one of the weapons from the vector.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks for your response - I'm a beginner at c++, do you have any code for how to make the pointer?

Comment: Not at the moment and I have to drive to the office asap..

Comment: @drescherjm Alright, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isCurrentWeapon shouldn't be a member of the class.  You should instead keep a pointer outside the class that points to whichever weapon is the current one.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
string ans;


class Weapon {

public:
    string name;
    int damage;        
    
public:

Weapon(string n, int d, bool iCW){
    name = n;
    damage = d;
}
};

Weapon* currentWeapon;


int main()
{
Weapon sword("Sword",30,true);
Weapon dagger("Dagger",10,false);
currentWeapon = &sword;
cout<<"Welcome to the Weapon Shop! Your current weapon is: " << currentWeapon->name;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution! Is this an example of deferencing in C++? Or is this something else?